# Python: 2 Dimensional List

Tags: python, list, matrix, python-3.3

**Problem**

I need to populate a list from a text file. The list should be a 2 dimensional list. I have been doing a series of activities for my online class, and I can't seem to find and make the right codes for it. Any help would be much appreciated. The text file should look like this:

***textfile.txt***

```
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
M N O P Q R 
S T U V W X
```

***expected output***

```
twoDlist = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
  ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
  ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'],
  ['S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X']
]
```

**my current code**

```
twoDlist = []
f = open("textfile.txt")
r = f.readlines()
for i in r:
    twoDlist.append(i.strip())
print(twoDlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix your existing code, your `i.strip()` should be replaced by [`i.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Demo:

```
twoDlist = []
f = open("textfile.txt")
r = f.readlines()
for i in r:
    twoDlist.append(i.split())
print(twoDlist)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'], ['S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X']]
```

A better way of doing this would be:

```
twoDlist = []
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    twoDlist = [line.split() for line in f]

print(twoDlist)
```

This way the file management is handled for you.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
twoDlist = map(str.split, f)
```

Update:
As pointed out by zondo, if you are using Python3, you should:

```
 twoDlist = list(map(str.split, f))
```

since map will return a map object instead of a list.

Comment: Yep, a careless typo. Thank you for your correction.